# Is there a specific format of how a Solana address should look like?

Tags: address

In bitcoin addresses can start with a 1, 3, or bech. And in Ethereum, it starts with 0x. Does Solana have a specific format to their addresses? Or is it just the base58 output with nothing added in?

Also is a public and private key a specific length? I measured public address is 44 characters and private key is 87 characters. Is this always the same?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solana address do not have a any specific starting value (like "0x" on Ethereum).

But like you pointed out, these addresses are base58 encoded version of a 32 byte array. Resulting in a specific string length between 32-44 characters long.

So if you wanted to perform some very simple validity format checks, you could use a regex like this:

```
[1-9A-HJ-NP-Za-km-z]{32,44}
```

##### Note that base58 strings will NOT use the entire regular English alphabet.

You can also read more about these on the Solana docs site here: https://docs.solana.com/integrations/exchange#basic-verfication

Answer (score 1):

> In bitcoin addresses can start with a 1, 3, or bech. And in Ethereum, it starts with 0x. Does Solana have a specific format to their addresses? Or is it just the base58 output with nothing added in?

**No specific format**

But you can generate [Vanity Addresses](https://smith-mcf.medium.com/solana-vanity-address-using-gpus-5a68ad94d1d4)

> Also is a public and private key a specific length? I measured public address is 44 characters and private key is 87 characters. Is this always the same?

**Yes**

Comment: private keys can sometimes be 88 characters and it still works.